# Unsatisfied dependencies for type X with qualifiers @Default

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, code-injection

I'm trying to inject an object of a given type (`Greeter`) on an EJB running inside Wildfly 8.2. However, the deployment always fails with the message

```
Unsatisfied dependencies for type Greeter with qualifiers @Default
```

I tried to annotate both the `GreeterImpl` and the injection point with `@Default` but that didn't also work. Am I missing something here?

My `Greeter` interface:

```
public interface Greeter {
    public void sayHi();
}
```

My `GreeterImpl` class (the only one that implements `Greeter`):

```
public class GreeterImpl implements Greeter {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GreeterImpl.class);

    @Override
    public void sayHi() {
        LOGGER.info("Hi!");
    }
}
```

My `ScheduledGreeter` EJB:

```
@Stateless
public class ScheduledGreeter {
    @Inject
    private Greeter greeter;

    @Schedule(second = "*/15", minute = "*", hour = "*")
    public void sayHi() {
        greeter.sayHi();
    }
}
```

Am I missing something about CDI here? Do I need a `beans.xml` at `META-INF` for this to work?

*Edit:* **I'm deploying this as `war` to Wildfly, if that even matters.**

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In Java EE 7, the default scanning for JARs/WARs is `annotated`, meaning that if you don't have a `beans.xml` that specifies the scan mode, it will default to annotated based scanning.

Your class, `GreeterImpl` has no bean defining annotations on it - no scopes particularly. You can override this by adding a `beans.xml` or by adding `@Dependent` (or other scope) to your `GreeterImpl`

Comment: The spec may be of use for you as well - http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#default_bean_discovery